# ASP.Net set Membership.Provider programmatically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, imperative

I would want to know if it is possible to set the default Membership provider (Membership.Provider) through code not through configuration file.

Comment: What is the purpose of such manipulation?

Comment: This might help. You can add them to the configuration file and then select which to run at runtime. I imagine you can also use your own custom class if you want instead (as long as it inherits from MembershipProvider of course)...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496647/set-active-membership-provider-programmatically

Comment: I think @Theo is onto your best bet.  You could create a proxy membership provider that just utilizes your desired membership provider based on whatever your criteria might be.

Comment: My scenario is rather complicated. Thank you all for your answers I was just interested in setting the Membership.Provider through code somehow. Now that I know it cannot be set imperative I will try and search a work arround. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not direct approach to your question. Instead, implement the custom membership provider, and use [IoC container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411660/enterprise-library-unity-vs-other-ioc-containers) (for example, [Enterprise Library Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649564.aspx)) to inject the desire class at run time.

For example,

```
public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
{
   var user = IoC.Resolve<IUserService>().GetUserByUsername(username, userIsOnline);
}
```